# Why is Series.apply() returning a dataframe instead of a series?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I'm trying to write a k-means algorithm from scratch. Suppose I have the following dataframe...

```
df = 
    a   b   c
0   1   4   [1, 2]
1   2   5   [1, 2]
2   3   6   [1, 2]
```

... where `c` represents the coordinates of a centroid and I want to calculate the Euclidean distance row-wise between, for example, point (a, b) and centroid (1, 2). I want to replace column `c` with the point-to-centroid distance for each row.

I have the following code:

```
df['c'].apply(lambda x: ((x[0]-df['a'])**2 + (x[1]-df['b'])**2)**0.5)
```

I expect it to return a 1-dimensional vector (Series) of length len(df):

```
0    2.000000
1    3.162278
2    4.472136
dtype: float64
```

But it returns a dataframe instead:

```
    0   1           2
0   2.0 3.162278    4.472136
1   2.0 3.162278    4.472136
2   2.0 3.162278    4.472136
```

What is the cause of this behavior? How do I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: It's because you're using `df['a']` and `df['b']` in the lambda. Those return 3 values (for the 3 rows in the df), and the result turns into 3 columns.

Comment: Right.  If you need the whole row, they do the `apply` against the whole dataframe with axis=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of the way you use `df['a']` and `df['b']` in the lambda. This isn't accessing the value in the same row as `df['c']`, it's referring to the entire series in each column, so 3 results are produced, and they become 3 columns in the result.

You can apply a function to the entire row, rather than just a single column. Specify `axis=1` when calling `df.apply()`.

```
df.apply(lambda x: ((x['c'][0]-x['a'])**2 + (x['c'][1]-x['b'])**2)**0.5, axis=1)
0    2.000000
1    3.162278
2    4.472136
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried so many things but of course not that...

Answer (score 3):

`df['a']` and `df['b']`, as used in the lambda, are Series, so the result is a Series, so `Series.apply` results in a DataFrame. (Per [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply): "If *func* returns a Series object the result will be a DataFrame.")

You don't even need to use `.apply` here since you can operate on the columns directly, though you need a workaround to get the nth elements of the lists; here `.str`.

```
((df['c'].str[0] - df['a'])**2 + (df['c'].str[1] - df['b'])**2) ** 0.5
```

Comment: I'll add that it's rarely a good idea to use lists in Series. It would have been even easier to have 2 columns for the centroid (one for each coordinate).

Answer (score 1):

Apply against the whole dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = [[1,4,[1,2]],[2,5,[1,2]],[3,6,[1,2]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['a','b','c'])
print(df)

df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: ((x['c'][0]-x['a'])**2 + (x['c'][1]-x['b'])**2)**0.5, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b       c
0  1  4  [1, 2]
1  2  5  [1, 2]
2  3  6  [1, 2]
   a  b         c
0  1  4  2.000000
1  2  5  3.162278
2  3  6  4.472136
```

Comment: Since this modifies the original df, you might want to put the result in a new column. `df['d'] = ...`

Comment: I think that's what he said he wanted -- replace the coordinate pair with a distance.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the motivation at the beginning where he said he wanted to replace `c`.